# Django app works when URLconf is empty, but sub directories are not being routed to Django

Tags: python, django, apache

There are a lot of questions here regarding the urls.py issues with Django. A lot seems to depend on how the web server is set up. Running locally in development mode, I get no problems with my Django app, but onced deployed to the webserver, it fails.

**the project urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('search.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**the app urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.search, name='search'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
def search(request):
    return HttpResponse("You're at the search page.")
```

**passenger_wsgi.py:**

```
import os
import sys
from app.wsgi import application
```

The empty path works `domain.com/app/` the 'include("search.urls")' works, but the path `domain.com/app/search/` and 'domain.com/app/admin' do not. Instead the '/app/search/' directs to a 404 not found page outside the django app. So there is something going on with the webserver that sub directories are not being routed to the Django app. Any help is appreciated.
The app is running on a Linux Apache 2.4.55 shared hosting server.

I have checked the raw error logs and other answers that were related to internal django urlconf issues but this seems to be outside of django.

I am looking at this site: https://thecodelearners.com/deploy-django-web-application-to-apache-server-step-by-step-guide/#create_and_configure_conf_file_for_django_app

But it is a bit over my head

Comment: Check that your Apache server is properly configured to handle requests to your domain. You can do this by visiting your domain `(e.g. http://example.com)` in a web browser and seeing if the default Apache page is displayed.

Comment: the domain and the rest of the website work fine.

Comment: I found that this was an issue with the .htaccess file in /public_html directory on the server. Running wordpress and django together creates conflict with URI redirecting. I needed to add a line to except the app sub directory:


# Add the following line to exclude the /excluded_directory/ path:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/excluded_directory/